# increase vlookup index column or looping

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to to get the whole row of vlookup value but it only gives one cell result unless i change the index column with every step, how is it possible to get the whole row or loop the fourmla till it gets the whole row or atleast specified number of cells. any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns("B:AZ")).Address & ",2,0),"""")"
End With
With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, 2).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to loop it as below but it doesn't work for the vlookup at the index column as below

```
For i = 2 To 6
With WS_Input
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns("B:AZ")).Address & ",i,0),"""")"
End With
With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, i).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, i).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: `",i,0),"""")"` is a string, namely: `,i,0),"")`. What you want is: `"," & i & ",0),"""")"` to get: `,2,0),"")` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Tables for such cases where we need not to work for the rest of the Cells of a specific columns.
And also we can use variables for the Col Index number (VLOOKUP) by obtaining through a inputbox or other options